# Serialising/deserialising data on android

Tags: deserialization, mobile, serialization, mobile-wallet-adapter

I am currently going though the Solana development course and I try to adapt what I learn onto an Android application. Everything is going great so far but now I am stuck when I try to serialise/deserialise data. I've tried to use Kotlin serialization to convert my data class into ByteArray with the following code: `Json.encodeToString(data).encodeToByteArray()`.

However I get an error saying that

> ' Program logged: "panicked at 'called `Result::unwrap()` on an `Err`
> value: Custom { kind: InvalidInput, error: "Unexpected length of
> input" }', src/instruction.rs:34:59"'

And when I try to deserialise the data as follow `val movies = connection.getProgramAccounts( serializer = BorshAsBase64JsonArraySerializer(MovieDe.serializer()), account =  PublicKey("CenYq6bDRB7p73EjsPEpiYN7uveyPUTdXkDkgUduboaN"), programAccountConfig = ProgramAccountConfig())`

I've got the following error:

> java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Failed to allocate a 1866989584 byte
> allocation with 2097152 free bytes and 184MB until OOM, target
> footprint 10037792, growth limit 201326592

Would anybody have some advice on how to serialise/deserialise data on Android?
Thanks in advance for your help and advice.

Answer (score 0):

the way you are deserializing your data is incorrect. You need to use the data struct of the account to serialize/deserialize it.

You need to create a data struct or if you are using an open source program with typescript bindings, you can find the program account data structs in program/js/src/accounts. [Example](https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/metaplex-program-library/blob/master/hydra/js/src/generated/accounts/FanoutMembershipVoucher.ts) from Metaplex Hydra. Import this file into your code to get deserialized data:

```
import { accountBeet } from './location/of/beet'
const account = new PublicKey(account);
let { data } = (await connection.getAccountInfo(account)) || {};
const deserialize = accountBeet.deserialize(data)[0];
```